# multiple usage of require() in Node.js return undefined results

Tags: node.js, require

I've got really strange behavior of require() in node.js.

I have simple common.js:

```
module.exports = common = {
    config: require('./config/config'),
    errorCodes: require('./config/errorCodes'),
    server: require('./server/server').server,
    dbManager: require('./db/dbManager').dbManager,
    idGenerator: require('./utils/idGenerator').idGenerator
};
```

my server.js:

```
var http = require('http'),
    url = require("url"),
    common = require('../common');

var server = (function ()
{
    var server = http.createServer(function (request, response)
    {

    });

    // running server
    function startServer()
    {
        server.listen(common.config.port);
        console.log('Tracking server running at :' + common.config.port);
    }

    return {
        startServer: startServer
    };
})();

module.exports.server = server;
```

**So, Case 1, - I'm reqiuring common only in server.js, it works:**

start.js:

```
//var common = require('./common');
var server = require('./server/server').server;

// initialize whole server
var init = function ()
{
//    common.dbManager.init();
    server.startServer();
};

init();
```

**And, Case 2, I'm requiring common in both modules - doesn't work:**

start.js

```
var common = require('./common');
var server = require('./server/server').server;

// initialize whole server
var init = function ()
{
    common.dbManager.init();
    server.startServer();
};

init();
```

The error is that in the second case certain properies common.config and common.dbManager are undefined. Does anybody have an idea why?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

Thanks guys, the following solution works:

> Your 'common' model is not needed: just require modules you need
>   explicitly

Answer (score 10):

You have a cycle: `server` -> `common` -> `server`.
Node.js `require()` returns `undefined` (by design) when module that is being loaded is required again, in cycle.

Solve your cycle.

Comment: If you can't live without the cycle, than at least move actual code (like the `init`) in process.nextTick(), or even better, have one place where you call the initialization manually. Your 'common' model is not needed: just require modules you need explicitly. They are cached, so no performance loss.

Comment: I believe you're right. I'll check tomorrow and let you guys know the result.